# Spring StoredProcedure Resultset value trim

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, whitespace

I currently have some code written using JAVA Spring 2.5.2 and JDBC to connect to the database and execute store procedures that return a `ResultSet`.  Because all of the database columns are defined as `char` (fixed length), the values that I am retreiving from the resultset contain whitespaces at the end.

I am currently extending the `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` class to access the databse and a simple `org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet` and `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper` combination to iterate over the resultset.

Is there a built-in function in Spring to go do this without having to call `org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimWhitespace(String)` for each String parameter in the resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no automated way to do that since you're pretty much getting the raw ResultSet and it's your responsibility to read the data and convert it however you want in order to match the properties in your DAO.

Comment: To bad there isn't a better way to do this.  I ended up decorating the ResultSet with another implementation that defers all of it's method calls to the original ResultSet but also performs a String trim when the getString method is called.